# RewriteBase not being applied

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp

I can't seem to get my .htaccess to work, I'm trying to rewrite all urls that aren't real files or folders to my index.php. The directory I'm in is /cms the rewrite only seems to work when I use this .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /cms/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I try and use the RewriteBase /cms/ and change the last line to . /index.php [L] like it's meant to be,  the rewrite doesn't rewrite to localhost/cms/index.php and instead it gets rewritten to localhost/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this version:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cms/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Note that I'm using `index.php` instead of `/index.php` with RewriteBase to make sure relative URI is loaded.

Comment: Works perfectly, I'm surprised I didn't pick up on that.